# How to validate SMTP credentials before sending email in PHP?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Since it's so hard to find an answer, I'm thinking this might be impossible. If so, I'd like confirmation that it's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not impossible.

You can program the SMTP interaction yourself and check for confirmation in the SMTP protocol that the credentials were accepted.  For that approach, you would have to do socket-level communication with the SMTP server (e.g. using the [PHP Sockets] service[1](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)).

To learn how the SMTP protocol works, try doing that with Telnet once by hand.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: Hmm, Microsoft link, I heard Microsoft doesn't even listen to all the SMTP standards. But you've answered the question. It's possible, just a little tricky.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar: If you google 'smtp telnet' there are plenty of Linux based tutorials as well :-)  I happened to use that one recently so know it is complete.

Answer (score 7):

There's a very simple way of doing it using recent versions of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

```
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'email@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'my_awesome_password';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->Port = 465;

// This function returns TRUE if authentication
// was successful, or throws an exception otherwise
$validCredentials = $mail->SmtpConnect();
```

You might need to change the port number and enable SSL depending on the targeted SMTP service. Gmail, for instance, *requires* a SSL connection.

To enable SSL, add `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

---

**Notice**: PHPMailer **throws exceptions** on failure. A username/password mismatch, for example, might trigger an exception. To avoid error messages getting printed all over your page, wrap the function inside a try/catch block.

```
$validCredentials = false;

try {
    $validCredentials = $mail->SmtpConnect();
}
catch(Exception $error) { /* Error handling ... */ }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It has helped me a lot. I too was getting errors at first until I saw the second half of your answer. This works for me.

Comment: this is the answer i was looking for this thing in last few days thank you @caiosm1005

Comment: @caiosm1005 The link is dead, maybe update with https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer or https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer ? The update queue is full, so I can't edit it.

Comment: @jirig took me almost a full year to see this, sorry. Link updated.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function does not support SMTP authentication.

You could consider a third party library, e.g.

http://swiftmailer.org/

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail

or maybe you could try the script [here](http://support.webecs.com/KB/a390/php-mail-script-with-smtp-authentication.aspx)

Comment: I'm already using a library to send SMTP emails, that's not the problem. Read the title.