# How to check smtp credentials without sending email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I want to confirm that my smtp credentials is correct or not without send any single email in codeigniter.

Is there any possibilities to achieve that without sending email ?

Comment: Only a guess, but have you tried to check for new e-mails, so receiving should also check your user details.

Comment: @NigelRen : Thanks for reply.Sorry i can't get your point.
But i am receiving email whenever i am trying to check smtp test connection on my email address.As i write my email address in "TO".I know that we can set  dummy email address as "TO" email address.But i don't want to send any email for testing purpose

Comment: When you receive your e-mail, you must be using your credentials to do this, otherwise anyone could fetch your e-mail.  So if you just need to check that you can log into the e-mail server, then I'd have thought that receiving e-mail would do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940424/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-email-in-php

Comment: @sintakonte Thanks for your reply.I got your point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate SMTP credentials before sending email in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940424/how-to-validate-smtp-credentials-before-sending-email-in-php)

Comment: @AntonMalmygin Thanks for reply but i asked here for specific framework not for core PHP.I know that any framework is the also core PHP.But want to know how manage using default functionalities of codeigniter framework.So Please don't make as duplicate